# React component, unexpected token error

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a basic stopwatch app, I'd like to tidy up my render function by putting markup into different methods, like this:

```
export default class stopwatch extends Component {
 render() {
 return <View style={styles.container}>
  <View style ={[styles.header, this.border('yellow')]}>
   <View style={this.border('red')} >
     <Text>
     00.00.00
     </Text>
     </View>
   <View style={this.border('green')} >
      {this.startStopButton()}
      {this.lapButton()}
   </View>
  </View>
 <View styles={[style.footer, this.border('blue')]}>
  <Text>
    List of Laps
  </Text>
 </View>
},
```

I'd like to tidy up my render function by putting markup into different methods, like this:

```
startStopButton: function(){
return <View>
          <Text>
            Start
          </Text>
        </View>
},
lapButton: function(){
     return <View>
        <Text>
          Lap
        </Text>
      </View>
 }


};
```

However, I keep getting the error, Unexpected Toekn line 27 which is this line

```
 startStopButton: function(){
return <View>
```

Any ideas whats wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using [ES6 classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). For class methods, you don't use the `function` keyword. Also, methods are not followed by commas. Drop the comma at the end of `render` and `startTopButton`:

```
export default class stopwatch extends Component {
  startStopButton() {
    return <View>
            <Text>
              Start
            </Text>
          </View>
  }

  lapButton() {
    return <View>
          <Text>
            Lap
          </Text>
        </View>
  }

  render() {
   return <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style ={[styles.header, this.border('yellow')]}>
     <View style={this.border('red')} >
       <Text>
       00.00.00
       </Text>
       </View>
     <View style={this.border('green')} >
        {this.startStopButton()}
        {this.lapButton()}
     </View>
    </View>
   <View styles={[style.footer, this.border('blue')]}>
    <Text>
      List of Laps
    </Text>
   </View>
  }
}
```